# Enviar dois inputs para verificação, ajax e php!

Tags: php, html5

Bom dia, tarde e noite. Estou com um problema em enviar dois valores com ajax, fazer a verificação desses valores, pra ver se já existem no bd e por fim retorna uma mensagem dizendo se existe ou não! o codigo que funcionava enviando apenas 1 valor é esse:

```
<input readonly maxlength="10" required class="inp_editar" type="text" name="fone_tel" id="fone"/>
                        <script language="javascript">
    var user_us = $("#fone");
    $("#resposta").hide();
        user_us.blur(function() { 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'verifica_cont.php', 
                type: 'POST', 
                data:{"fone" : user_us.val()}, 
                success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data); 
                data = $.parseJSON(data); 
                $("#resposta").text(data.user_us);
                $("#resposta").fadeIn();
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

E o verifica_cont.php

```
<?php
#Verifica se tem um email para pesquisa
include('../../connect/config.php');
if(isset($_POST['fone'])){ 
    if(empty($_POST['fone']) || $_POST['fone'] == "_____-____" || $_POST['fone'] == "____-____"){
    echo json_encode(array('user_us' => 'Preencha o contato do Contribuinte'));     
    }else{
    #Recebe o Email Postado
    $userPostado = $_POST['fone'];

    #Conecta banco de dados
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM n_contribuintes_tel WHERE fone_tel = '{$userPostado}' ") or print mysql_error();

    #Se o retorno for maior do que zero, diz que já existe um.
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0) 
        echo json_encode(array('user_us' => 'Telefone já cadastrado, tente outro!')); 
    else
        echo json_encode(array('user_us' => 'Telefone valido!' )); 
    }
}
?>
```

Esse de cima, funciona perfeitamente, já tentei de diversas formas, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer com dois inputs, a ultima tentativa em enviar os dois valores foi essa:

```
<input readonly maxlength="10" required class="inp_editar" type="text" name="fone_tel" id="fone"/>
                <input  maxlength="10" required class="inp_editar" type="text" name="ramal_tel" id="ramal_tel"/>
                        <script language="javascript">
    var user_us = $("#fone");
     var user_us_ramal = $("#ramal_tel"); 
    $("#resposta").hide();
        user_us.blur, user_us_ramal.blur(function() { 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'verifica_cont.php', 
                type: 'POST', 
                data:{"fone" : user_us.val(), "ramal_tel" : user_us_ramal.val()}, 
                success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data); 
                data = $.parseJSON(data); 
                $("#resposta").text(data.user_us);
                $("#resposta").fadeIn();
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

verifica_cont.php

```
<?php
#Verifica se tem um email para pesquisa
include('../../connect/config.php');
if(isset($_POST['fone'])){ 
    if(empty($_POST['fone']) || $_POST['fone'] == "_____-____" || $_POST['fone'] == "____-____"){
    echo json_encode(array('user_us' => 'Preencha o contato do Contribuinte'));     
    }else{
    #Recebe o Email Postado
    $userPostado = $_POST['fone'];
    $userPostado_s = $_POST['ramal_tel'];

    #Conecta banco de dados
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM n_contribuintes_tel WHERE fone_tel = '{$userPostado}' and ramal_tel = '{$userPostado_s}'") or print mysql_error();

    #Se o retorno for maior do que zero, diz que já existe um.
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0) 
        echo json_encode(array('user_us' => 'Telefone já cadastrado, tente outro!')); 
    else
        echo json_encode(array('user_us' => 'Telefone valido!' )); 
    }
}
?>
```

Mas não funcionou também!

Se alguém poder me ajudar, obrigado!

Comment: O que exatamente não funcionou? Em que linha que da erro?

Comment: <script language="javascript">
var user_us = $("#fone"); 
$("#resposta").hide();
     user_us.blur(function() { 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'verifica_cont.php', 
                type: 'POST', 
    data:{"fone" : user_us.val()}, 
                success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data); 
                data = $.parseJSON(data); 
                $("#resposta").text(data.user_us);
    $("#resposta").fadeIn();
       } 
   }); 
 }); </script>
eu não consegui enviar o valor de dois inputs pra verificação, eu so consigo enviar #fone @AndrewRibeiro

Comment: `mysql_query` está depreciado em versões superiores ao mysql 5, além disso você está permitindo sql injection na sua query de telefone. Conseguiria facilmente apagar todos os telefones do seu banco. usando o seu input, com  `$userPostado = "' or  1';
        DELETE * FROM n_contribuintes_tel where  1;--  '";`

Comment: Recomendo usar `mysqli_*` ou `PDO`, e tratar a query com placeholders.

Comment: Começa o erro neste método blur... Não se usa blur assim: `user_us.blur`, é `user_us.blur()`. E essa vírgula está estranha.

Comment: Mude `<script language="javascript">` para `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Comment: Além disso, vc não precisa fazer parseJSON se está enviando ajax, basta solicitar o tipo no objeto `dataType: 'json',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {

var user_us = $("#fone"), 
    user_us_ramal = $("#ramal_tel"); 
    $("#resposta").hide();
        $("#fone,#ramal_tel").blur(function() { 
            var valA = user_us.val(), valB = user_us_ramal.val();

            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'verifica_cont.php', 
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:'json',                
                data: {"fone" : valA, "ramal_tel":valB}, 
                success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data); 
                $("#resposta").html(data.fone+'<br>'+data.ramal_tel)
                    .fadeIn();
            } 
        }); 
    }); 

});
```

Veja funcionando no [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/483o5dud/).